# Create numpy array within numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a numpy array within a numpy array. If i do it with normal python its something like

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]

a[0][1] = [1,1,1]

print a
```

The result is [[1, [1, 1, 1]], [3, 4]]

How can I achieve the same using numpy arrays? The code I have is:

```
a = np.array([(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6)])
b = np.array([1,1,1])

a[0][1] = b
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have to convert each number in the 2D numpy array into another array

Comment: @ShayaanAzad. Yes, but **why**?

Comment: If you need to do this, use a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` as created is dtype int.  Each element can only be another integer:

```
In [758]: a = np.array([(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6)])
     ...: b = np.array([1,1,1])
     ...: 
In [759]: a
Out[759]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [760]: b
Out[760]: array([1, 1, 1])
In [761]: a[0,1]=b
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

You can make another dtype of array, one that holds pointers to objects, much as list does:

```
In [762]: aO = a.astype(object)
In [763]: aO
Out[763]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```

Now it is possible to replace one of those element pointers with a pointer to `b` array:

```
In [765]: aO[0,1]=b
In [766]: aO
Out[766]: 
array([[1, array([1, 1, 1]), 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```

But as asked in the comments - why do you want/need to do this?  What are you going to do with such an array?  It is possible to do some `numpy` math on such an array, but as shown in some recent SO questions, it is hit-or-miss.  It is also slower.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do this. Numpy arrays cannot have entries of varying shape. Your request to make an array like `[[1, [1, 1, 1]], [3, 4]]` is impossible. However, you could make a numpy matrix of dimensions (3x2x3) to get

```
[
 [
  [1,0,0],
  [1,1,1],
  [0,0,0],
 ]
 [
  [3,0,0],
  [4,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
 ]
]
```

Your only option is to pad empty elements with some number (I used `0`s above) or use another data structure.